# List view web part - auto refresh

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-part, list-view

I created page with a list view web part. When I modify list view I noticed that view in web part didn't change.

Is it possible to make it auto refresh every time the list view is changed? Maybe some code could help?

Answer (score 2):

When we select a view in a list view web part, it gets the view settings only once and disconnects from the source view. If you change the source view, the new settings wouldn't reflect.

[image]

I would suggest you to check how frequent you change the source view and then decide whether to go for a custom code solution or change the web part view settings manually.